# Codeigniter: Table List using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

[table list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHca6.png)

My mind is is boggling for this logic.When I click the ADD SECTION button, a modal opens asking for input values. What I want is that, all the values from that modal will be listed on the TABLE below the ADD Section. Each row to have different names for post method. Can please anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: click the table list to show the image guys. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to create multiple rows and then submit them as a form. Use jQuery to append table rows and to create cells containing input fields. You can set those input field names as an array `<input type="text" name="section[]" value="somevaluefrommodal">`

Basic html layount should look something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // click handler
  $("#add-row").on("click", function() {
    $("table").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="section[]" value="Section2"/></td><td><input type="text" name="test[]" value="Test2"/></td></tr>');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-row">Add Row</button>
<form>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Test</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="section[]" value="Section1"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="test[]" value="Test1"/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="section[]" value="Section2"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="test[]" value="Test2"/></td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly!. Additionally, how can I make that every add row that I added will increment name? For example: column[0][section], column[1][section],....

Thank you so much

Comment: You need to do it with Javascript while creating those rows dynamically. This is how you get a current number of rows: `$("table").children().length`

Comment: Thank you so much sir. God bless

Comment: No problem. Just one thing - Mark the question as answered if it's done.