# How to display records on key pressed using ajax or php?

Tags: php, json, ajax, mysqli, keypress

I am able to display the records on page and search is also working after clicking on the search button. Now my issue is how to display records on key pressed.

For example- I have 100 records on the same page if any user types anything on the search text field that records will search and display on the screen.

Would you help me in this?

**HTML**

```
<script>
 $(function () {
 $('#valueToSearch').on('keyup',function(){
  //Your ajax call will go Here
  $.ajax({
    url:senddata.php, // separate file for search
    data : {
      q : $('#valueToSearch').val().trim()
    },
    method:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        $('#fetch_record').html(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
     alert("something has gone wrong");
    }
  });
});
});
    </script>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"><br><br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>

  <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['lastname'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**senddata.php**

```
    if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q'] !=''){
$valueToSearch = $_POST['q'];

// your sql query for Searching result
$query = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id=$row["id"];
        $fn=$row["firstname"];
        $ln=$row["lastname"];
        $email=$row["email"];
    }
}
return json_encode($id, $fn, $ln, $email);
}
```

Comment: https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/creating-autocomplete-functionality-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I updated my code. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

for that you have to work around with [Ajax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm), and there will be lots of changes, and i hope you are clear with basic concepts of Javascript

Below code will give you a headstart.

```
$('#searchboxID').on('keyup',function(){
  //Your ajax call will go Here
  $.ajax({
    url:senddata.php, // separate file for search
    data : {
      q : $('#searchboxID').val().trim()
    },
    method:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
      // replace your data in html
    },
    error:function(data){
     alert("something has gone wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

IN sendata.php

```
if(isset($_POST['q']) && $_POST['q'] !=''){
// your sql query for Searching result
return your result in json encoded format
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Krunal, I am not aware of JSON. Can you help me with the code? Please

Comment: Of  course,what you do when you are not aware of something, you learn

Comment: Mr.Krunal, Do you have any other solution for this?

Comment: this is far as anyone will post on this, and no this is what came with in sort time. accept it if it helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145538/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-krunal-limbad).

Answer (score 0):

1. This is how you detect input change and get the value from the input box.

```js
$("input").keyup(function(e){
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

2. @Krunal explained how to make an ajax call
3. Modify your search code so your search `$_POST['valueToSearch']` matches parameter name in the ajax request @Krunal wrote it (smth like `$_POST['q']`. NOTE - SANITIZE RECEIVED DATA BEFORE EXECUTING QUERIES LIKE THAT
4. Your php script should return json encoded array using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. You can simply echo the resulting string.
5. Handle echoed data with `success` attribute in the ajax call. Start by simply `console.log()`-ing it and work your way to step 6.
6. Walk the received array and append created html elements into parent container. Sample in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255133/codeigniter-table-list-using-javascript-and-php/44259713)

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Bramastic, But how can I connect your code with database

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found my solution using Ajax and I did with a prepared statement. First I am displaying all records in the index page and if user anything type in a search that will pass throw Ajax to the process page and return on the index page.

Please check my code and assist me more secure and easy way or reduce the number of line of code.

**Index.php**

```
    <input type="text" name="search" >
    <div id="table-container">
    <?php 
    $query="SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, message, location FROM test";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $message, $location);
        echo '<table border="1"';
        echo '<tr>
            <th>Id</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email.</th>
          <th>Message</th>
          <th>location</th>
        </tr>';

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
          echo'<tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="" name="checkbox[]" value='.$id.'></td>
               <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
               <td>'.$lastname.'</td>
               <td>'.$email.'</td>
               <td>'.$message.'</td>
               <td>'.$location.'</td>
          </tr>
               ';
        }
            echo '</table>';
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
    </table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
                     {
        $("input[name='search']").on('keyup',function()
           {
            var keyword = $(this).val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:'process.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:'request='+keyword,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $("#table-container").html(data);
                    //alert(data);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Process.php**

```
$request=$_POST['request'];

$query="SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, message, location FROM `test` WHERE firstname LIKE '%" .$request. "%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$request  ."%' OR email LIKE '%" .$request ."%' OR location LIKE '%" .$request ."%'";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $message, $location);

    echo '<table border="1"';
    echo '<tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email.</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>location</th>
    </tr>';

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      echo'<tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="" name="checkbox[]" value='.$id.'></td>
           <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
           <td>'.$lastname.'</td>
           <td>'.$email.'</td>
           <td>'.$message.'</td>
           <td>'.$location.'</td>
      </tr>
           ';
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$conn->close();
```